# Uploading files directly from C drive to Server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to upload files to server by giving file list in text file like

c:\file1.ext
c:\file2.ext

is this possible without using UploadFile control or form method in asp.net c# ?

Comment: The server and client are on the same LAN?

Comment: Indeed. Just write client app that post these files to server. Should be pretty straight forward with `WebClient` class (or even `WebRequest` if you like it more). Or you have some restrictions on what type of code you can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if the server and client are on the same LAN or VPN, you can think of using this:

```
 String source = @"c:\file1.ext";
 String desctrination = @"\\SERVER\TRANSFERDATA\file1.ext";

 File.Move(source, desctrination);
```

or

```
File.Copy(source, desctrination);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to grab files from client's machine without using fileupload controls.
Http protocol doesn't allow to do that.
You could have file transfer on client's machine and it could send you those files, or you could have web service for uploading files, but you can't directly grab files from client's machine

Answer (score 1):

If you want a quick and easy answer no, but there is no such thing as impossible!! you can do one of those options:

- Creating WCF service and let client install it  in his PC.
- Using ActiveX.

in video link  Below you can see that ASP.net application accessing point of sale device that plug to client PC, now if that application can access device, you can access the C drive..

[Connect to POS device throw asp.net](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s9bYeaSwOFA)